# Broadcasting the dot product of a list of 2D points with a 2x2 matrix

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a list of points xy with the shape(2,100). I want to take the dot product with a 2x2 matrix as follows:

```
g = xy.T@W@xy
```

which should result in a vector of 100 values. How can I do this with Python?

I know it should result in 100 values because the above express works well if I feed in one 2D point. How can I vectorize the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ij,ik,kj->j',xy,W,xy, optimize=True)
```

Comment: I made a mistake. I need xy.T@W@xy as opposed to xy@W@xy.T. What do I need to change?

Comment: @saad As you have pointed out in the question - `xy with the shape(2,100).`. So, no change is needed.